# How does the percentage sign % work within minipages?

Tags: symbols, minipage, syntax

I am using minipages to arrange three `verbatim` blocks horizontally. Here is my code:

```
\section*{Problem 1 : Solution} 
    \begin{enumerate}[label={(\alph*)}]
        \item Excuting the following code, we can get: \\ \\
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
            \begin{verbatim}
                y=rnorm(10,50,7)
                stem(y)
                qqnorm(y)

                  3 | 7
                  4 | 2368
                  5 | 15
                  6 | 355
            \end{verbatim}
        \end{minipage}
%
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
            \begin{verbatim}
                y=rnorm(10,50,7)
                stem(y)
                qqnorm(y)

                  3 | 07
                  4 | 13567
                  5 | 135
            \end{verbatim}
        \end{minipage}
%
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\linewidth}
            \begin{verbatim}
                y=rnorm(10,50,7)
                stem(y)
                qqnorm(y)

                  3 | 
                  3 | 5
                  4 | 
                  4 | 77
                  5 | 011334
                  5 | 6
            \end{verbatim}
        \end{minipage}

        \item
        \item
    \end{enumerate}
```

It looks pretty good:

[image]

However, if I get rid of the two % signs separating minipages, I would get the following result:

[image]

I thought % in latex is only for commenting. My question is why do we add % between minipages? Is that the rule of using minipages?

Comment: I think this is just the standard `%` eating the new line, see [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/106162)  You should see the same if you get rid of the blank line between `\end{minipage}` and `\begin{minipage}`.

Comment: An empty line gives a new paragraph. If you comment the empty line it isn't there any more. You don't need minipages, simple words would show the same effect.

Comment: Without the `%` you have a blank line which is, as usual, the way you insert a paragraph break. With the `%` you have just spaces between them because the previous line ending is not commented `\end{minipage}` and a line ending is interpreted as a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing special about `minipage` here, you are just removing a paragraph break, normally you should also have a `%` after `minipage` to remove the word space as well, compare 1 2 and 3 below which are the same as your examples but using words rather than `minipage`.

[image]

(1) has word spaces (2) has no space (3) has paragraph beaks.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

1 one
%
two
%
three

2 one%
%
two%
%
three

3 one

two

three

\end{document}
```